# Is there a simpler solution for Codingbat fix45?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to solve this CodingBat problem:

> (This is a slightly harder version of the fix34 problem.) Return an array that contains exactly the same numbers as the given array, but rearranged so that every 4 is immediately followed by a 5. Do not move the 4's, but every other number may move. The array contains the same number of 4's and 5's, and every 4 has a number after it that is not a 4. In this version, 5's may appear anywhere in the original array.

```
fix45({5, 4, 9, 4, 9, 5}) → {9, 4, 5, 4, 5, 9}
fix45({1, 4, 1, 5}) → {1, 4, 5, 1}
fix45({1, 4, 1, 5, 5, 4, 1}) → {1, 4, 5, 1, 1, 4, 5}
```

I initially used a method which passed all of the sites tests, but I don't think it would work for longer arrays. The initial method used 2 loops and did not use a new array. I have created a solution which introduces a new array and a 3rd nested loop and I believe will work for all instances of the problem. However, the site states that the problems in this section can be solved with 2 loops, so I am wondering if there actually is a 2 loop solution that will work for *any*instance of the problem. Here is the question and my 3 loop solution:

```
public int[] fix45(int[] nums) {

    int[] locations = {-1};

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; ++i) {

        if (nums[i] == 4) {

            JLoop:
            for (int j = nums.length-1; j >= 0; --j) {
                if (nums[j] == 5) {
                    for (int k = locations.length-1; k>=0 ; --k) {
                        if (locations[k] == j) {
                            continue JLoop;
                        } 
                    }
                    nums[j] = nums[i + 1];
                    nums[i + 1] = 5;
                    locations[locations.length - 1] = i+1;
                    locations = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(locations,
                            locations.length + 1);
                    locations[locations.length-1] = -1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return nums;

}
```

Comment: I think the root cause of your difficulty may be in reading the problem statement. It says "every other number may move" without saying anything at all about preserving order among them. It looks as though you are adding a requirement to preserve order. Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Restarting the search for a suitable 5 from one end of the array every time a 4 is found seems wasteful. Part of the array has already been scanned and is known not to contain a 5 that can be moved. This is O(n) time and O(1) space.

```
    public static int[] fix45(int[] nums) {

      int j = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; ++i) {
        if (nums[i] == 4 && nums[i + 1] != 5) {
          /*
           * Need to find the next movable 5 That means an element that is 5 and
           * either is the first element or is preceded by anything other than 4
           */
          while (nums[j] != 5 || (j != 0 && nums[j - 1] == 4)) {
            j++;
          }
          nums[j] = nums[i + 1];
          nums[i + 1] = 5;
        }
      }
      return nums;
    }
```

Comment: Note that this method doesn't preserve the other elements' orders (try the case `{5, 2, 5, 4, 1, 4}`), but +1 due to CodingBat's ambiguous problem statement and nice space usage. (CodingBat remains ambiguous in its test cases.)

Comment: I'm lazy. When writing an algorithm, I go for the best solution I can find to the stated problem, without making it harder for myself, or slower for the computer, by assuming additional requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Using an extra array, here's a solution with "one loop" (loops without nested loops):

```
public int[] fix45(int[] nums) {
  int[] otherValues = new int[nums.length];

  for(int i = 0, c = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    if(nums[i] != 4 && nums[i] != 5)
      otherValues[c++] = nums[i];

  for(int i = 0, c = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    if(nums[i] == 4)
      nums[++i] = 5;
    else
      nums[i] = otherValues[c++];

  return nums;
}
```

We fix the fours, take out the non-fours and non-fives, and put the values all back in in order.

To improve the space usage (perhaps not by much), you can count the number of fours before you make the extra array.

Comment: +1, Very creative solution. Minimal use of brackets.

Comment: Exactly how I cracked it :P

Answer (score 1):

```
public int[] fix45(int[] nums) {

 int t=0;
  for(int i=0; i< nums.length ; i++)
     for(int j=0;j<nums.length ; j++)

     if(nums[i]==5 && nums[j]==4)
     {
      t=nums[j+1];
      nums[j+1]=nums[i];
      nums[i]=t;
     }
     return nums;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix after dansalmos remark:

```
public int[] fix45(int[] nums) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {

        if (nums[i] == 4) {
            if(nums[i+1] == 5) continue;

            for( int j = 0; i < nums.length; j++){
                if(nums[j] == 5 && (j==0 || nums[j-1] != 4)){
                    nums[j] = nums[i+1];
                    nums[i+1] = 5;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return nums;
}
```

Comment: does not pass these tests on [codingbat](http://codingbat.com/prob/p125819) `fix45({5, 4, 5, 4, 1}) → {1, 4, 5, 4, 5}`
`fix45({4, 5, 4, 1, 5}) → {4, 5, 4, 5, 1}`

Answer (score 0):

The following method will run in O(n) time using O(n) space:

```
public int[] fix45(int[] nums) {

    if (nums == null || nums.length <= 1) {
        return nums;
    }

    // store all the 5s pos
    int[] pos = new int[nums.length];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 5) {
            pos[j++] = i;
        }
    }

    j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= nums.length - 2; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 4 && nums[i + 1] != 5) {
            if (j >= pos.length) {
                System.err
                        .println("No more 5s: there are more 4 than 5 in the input array");
                break;
            }
            // fix45 swapping
            nums[pos[j++]] = nums[i + 1];
            nums[i + 1] = 5;
        }
    }

    return nums;

}
```

Comment: Does not pass `fix45({4, 5, 4, 1, 5}) → {4, 5, 4, 5, 1}` and your print warning is not allowed on codingbat.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] fix45(int[] nums) {
  int idx4 = -1;
  int idx5 = -1;
  while (true) {
    while (true) { // find a 4 without a 5 after it
      idx4 = find(nums, 4, ++idx4);
      if (idx4 == -1)  // done if no more 4's
        return nums;
      if (nums[idx4+1] != 5)
        break;
    }
    while (true) { // find a 5 without a 4 before it
      idx5 = find(nums, 5, ++idx5);
      if (idx5 == 0 || nums[idx5-1] != 4)
        break;
    }
    nums[idx5] = nums[idx4+1];  // swap the 4 and 5
    nums[idx4+1] = 5;
  }
}

public int find(int[] nums, int num, int start) {
  for (int i = start; i < nums.length; i++)
    if (nums[i] == num)
      return i;
  return -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] fix45(int[] nums) {
   if (nums.length < 2) {
   return nums;
   }
        int index = 0;
        int index2 = 0;
        int index3 = 0;
        int[] only5 = fives(nums);
        int[] after4 = new int[count4(nums)];
        for (int a = 0; a < nums.length - 1; a++) {
            if (nums[a] == 4) {
                after4[index] = nums[a + 1];
                index++;
                nums[a + 1] = only5[index2];
                index2++;
            }
        }
//This while loop gets the frst number that is not a 5 that is after a 4
        while (nums[0] == 5) {
            nums[0] = after4[index3];
            index3++;
        }

        if (nums[nums.length - 2] != 4 && nums[nums.length - 1] == 5) {
            nums[nums.length - 1] = after4[index3];
            index3++;
        }
        for (int b = 1; b < nums.length; b++) {
            if (nums[b] == 5 && nums[b - 1] != 4) {
                nums[b] = after4[index3];
                index3++;
            }
        }
        return nums;
    }
    public int count4(int[] nums) {
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int e : nums) {
            if (e == 4) {
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        return cnt;
    }
    public int[] fives(int[] nums) {
        int index = 0;
        int[] only5 = new int[count4(nums)];
        for (int e : nums) {
            if (e == 5) {
                only5[index] = e;
                index++;
            }
        }
        return only5;
    }
```

//long solution, scroll up

Comment: Even this code could be the solution, could you please add more details and explain more?

Comment: I have a few if's to for base cases and a helper method counting 4's which according to the problem statements,  #4 = #5. I make use 2 for loops to pass through the array and put the correct values at the right spots. The first loops stores the values after the 4 and puts the first 5, for, the five array into that spot and moves on. The second loops cleans it all up by finding 5's that are in the wrong places or (the original places where the numbers to go after the 4's and replacing the occupying 5's with the original values after the 4's, which were put into an array before becoming a five.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this thread is years old, but I just wanted to add my solution:

```
public int[] fix45(int[] nums){

    int notAFourOrFive = 0;

    int[] ary = new int[nums.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 4) {
            ary[i] = 4;
            ary[i+1] = 5;
        }
        else if (nums[i] != 5) {
            notAFourOrFive = nums[i];
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < ary.length; j++) {
        if (ary[j] == 0) {
            ary[j] = notAFourOrFive;
        }
    }

    return ary;
}
```

Seeing as the amount of `4`s and `5`s are equal, it is safe to add them to a new array whenever a `4` is found. It is safe to use `i+1` in this case, because a `4` never comes at the end of the array. It is also safe to set the 'other' number whenever a non-`4` or non-`5` is reached, because all the other numbers are the same, in each test.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] fix45(int[] nums) 
{
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
    {
        if(nums[i]==5)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<nums.length; j++)
            if(nums[j]==4&&nums[j+1]!=5)
            {
                f(nums, i, j+1);
            }
        }
    }
    return nums;
}
///this "helper" function swaps 2 elements of the array
public void f(int []nums , int m, int n)
{
    int t= nums[m];
    nums[m] =nums[n];
    nums[n] = t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     public int[] fix45(int[] nums) {

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {

        if (nums[i] == 5 && i == 0 || nums[i] == 5 && nums[i - 1] != 4) {

            int a5 = i;

            for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {

                if (nums[j] == 4 && nums[j + 1] != 5) {

                    int temp = nums[j + 1];

                    nums[j + 1] = 5;
                    nums[a5] = temp;

                    break;
                }

            }

        }
    }

    return nums;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution that works that I have found.
Simply create ArrayLists that track the 4's and 5's, and swap the values.
How's this for easy to understand?

```
public int[] fix45(int[] nums) 
{
        //Create a copy array to manipulate and eventually return.
        int[] ret = nums;
        //Create two ArrayLists that let us track for and five positions.
        ArrayList<Integer> fourPositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> fivePositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //Get the positions of fours and fives and add them to their respective ArrayLists.
        for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
        {
          if (ret[i] == 4)
          {
            fourPositions.add(i);
          }
          if (ret[i] == 5)
          {
            fivePositions.add(i);
          }
        }
        //Swap all of the places right after the fours with a respective number of the fives,
        for (int i = 0; i < fourPositions.size(); i++)
        {
          int temp = ret[fourPositions.get(i) + 1];
          ret[fourPositions.get(i) + 1] = ret[fivePositions.get(i)];
          ret[fivePositions.get(i)] = temp;
        }
        //Return the array.
        return ret;
 }
```

Comment: If you are trying this on codingbat.com, there is something wrong with the way they compile it on one of the problems. I tested in NetBeans and it gives the right answer, so there is a problem with codingbat's web compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses LinkedHashSet. I think O-notation for time is *O(n)*, and for space is also *O(n)*.

```
  public int[] fix45(int[] nums) {
  Set<Integer> ind4 = new LinkedHashSet<>();
  Set<Integer> ind5 = new LinkedHashSet<>();

  //Store positions for all fours and fives except those fives
  //that immediately follow number four.
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
    if (nums[i] == 4){
      ind4.add(i);
      if (i + 1 < nums.length && nums[i + 1] == 5){
        i++;
      } 
    }else if (nums[i] == 5){
      ind5.add(i);
    } 
  } 

  Iterator<Integer> iter5ind = ind5.iterator();

  for (Integer i : ind4){
    if (i + 1 > nums.length || !iter5ind.hasNext()) break;
    if (nums[i + 1] == 5){
      continue;
    }
    int j = iter5ind.next();

    int tmp = nums[i + 1];
    nums[i + 1] = nums[j];
    nums[j] = tmp;
  }
  return nums;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Fix45 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assertArrays(new int[]{9, 4, 5, 4, 5, 9}, new int[]{5, 4, 9, 4, 9, 5});
        assertArrays(new int[]{1, 4, 5, 4, 5}, new int[]{5, 4, 5, 4, 1});
        assertArrays(new int[]{1, 1, 4, 5, 4, 5}, new int[]{5, 5, 4, 1, 4, 1});
        assertArrays(new int[]{4, 5, 4, 5, 1}, new int[]{4, 5, 4, 1, 5});
        assertArrays(new int[]{4, 5, 4, 5, 2}, new int[]{4, 2, 4, 5, 5});
    }

    public static int[] fix45(int[] nums) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if(nums[i] == 4 && nums[i + 1] != 5){

                int location = i + 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {

                    if(nums[j] == 4 && nums[j + 1] == 5){
                        j++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (nums[j] == 5) {
                        int temp = nums[j];
                        nums[j] = nums[location];
                        nums[location] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return nums;
    }


    private static void assertArrays(int[] expected, int[] input) {
        int[] actual = fix45(input);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(actual));
        boolean status = Arrays.equals(expected, actual);
        System.out.println(status);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, explain a little bit what your solution does.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many complicated code in here. I think we simplified like this :

```
public int[] fix45(int[] nums) {        
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (nums[i] == 4) {
                for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
                    if (nums[j] == 5) {
                        if (j > 0 && nums[j - 1] != 4) {
                            int tmp = nums[i + 1];
                            nums[i + 1] = 5;
                            nums[j] = tmp;
                        } else if (j == 0) {
                            int tmp = nums[i + 1];
                            nums[i + 1] = 5;
                            nums[j] = tmp;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return nums;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add My Solution, as far I tested on CodingBat and passed all test and without use of 2 for loops

```
    public int[] fix45(int[] nums) {
        if (nums.length == 0 || nums.length == 1 || nums.length == 2) {
            return nums;
        }

        int indexof4 = 0, indexof5 = 0;
        int indexToWorkonForRplcmnt = -1;
        while (indexof4 < nums.length && indexof5 < nums.length) {
            if ((indexof4 + 1) < nums.length && nums[indexof4] == 4 && nums[indexof4 + 1] != 5) {
                indexToWorkonForRplcmnt = indexof4 + 1;
//                System.out.println("IndexOf4:"+indexToWorkonForRplcmnt);

            } else {
                indexof4++;
            }

            if ((indexof5) < nums.length && nums[indexof5] == 5) {

                if (indexof5 == 0 && nums[indexof5] == 5) {
//                    System.out.println("IndexOf5:"+indexof5);
                } else if (nums[indexof5 - 1] != 4 && nums[indexof5] == 5) {
//                    System.out.println("IndexOf5:"+indexof5);
                } else {
                    indexof5++;
                }

            } else {
                indexof5++;
            }

            if (indexToWorkonForRplcmnt != -1 && (indexof5) < nums.length && nums[indexof5] == 5) {
                System.out.println("IndexOf4:" + indexToWorkonForRplcmnt);
                System.out.println("IndexOf5:" + indexof5);
                int temp = nums[indexToWorkonForRplcmnt];
                nums[indexToWorkonForRplcmnt] = nums[indexof5];
                nums[indexof5] = temp;
                indexToWorkonForRplcmnt = -1;
                indexof4++;
                indexof5++;
            }

        }
        return nums;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple answer :)

```
 public int[] fix45(int[] nums) {
  int p5=0;//tracker for 5's

  for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
    if(nums[i] == 4){// got a 4 
      for(int j = p5 ;j<nums.length;j++){
        //finding a 5 for that 4 at nums[i]
        if(nums[j] == 5 && ( (j > 0 && nums[j-1]!=4 ) || (j==0) )){
          // found 5 and checking if it is not preceded by a 4      
          //swap if not preceded by a 4
          int temp = nums[i+1];
          nums[i+1] = nums[j];
          nums[j] = temp;

          p5 = j;//set the tracker to where we found 5 for nums[i]
          break;//break out of loop
        }
      } 
    }
  }

  return nums;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in one while loop also !

```
  public int[] fix45(int[] nums) {


      int start = 0;
      int end = nums.length-1;

      boolean is4 = false;
      boolean is5 = false;


      while( start < nums.length ){

        if(nums[start] == 4 && nums[start+1]!=5){
          is4 = true;
        }

        if(nums[end] == 5 && (end == 0 || (end-1>=0 && nums[end-1]!=4))){
          is5 = true;
        }


        if(is4 && is5){
          int temp = nums[start+1];
          nums[start+1] = nums[end];
          nums[end] = temp;

          is4 = false;
          is5 = false;
          end = nums.length-1;
        }



        if(is4){
          end--;
          continue;
        }

        start++;
      }
      return nums;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] fix45(int[] nums) {
    int[] array = new int[nums.length];
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          if (nums[i]==4) {
              array[i] = 4;
              array[i+1]= 5;
          }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i]!=4 && nums[i]!=5) {
            temp = nums[i];
            }
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j]==0) {
                array[j]=temp;
            }
        }


    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: Would be a lot interesting if you could also add an explanation to the code :)

Comment: Hey @Balastrong , firstly I created a blank array and copied all the 4s (maintaining their indexes) and added a following 5 onto them . E.g for the test fix45([5, 4, 9, 4, 9, 5]), our blank array would now look like [0, 4, 5, 4, 5, 0]. Then I used a loop to identify a non 4 or 5 element in the nums array and I temporarily stored it in the variable temp. I then searched for a 0 in my new array and filled it in with this, e.g. [9, 4, 5, 4, 5, 0] then [9, 4, 5, 4, 5, 9] (The 0s represent non 4 or 5 elements). I'm not too sure if I explained this well enough, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Simplest probably:

for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
 if(nums[i] == 5 && i == 0 || nums[i] == 5 && nums[i-1] != 4){
   int pos5 = i;
   for(int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++){
     if(nums[j] == 4 && nums[j+1] != 5){
       int temp = nums[j+1];
       nums[j+1] = 5;
       nums[pos5] = temp;
       break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return nums;
```

Comment: Please use code markus when you post code in your answer.